# JS globals cause to crash on evaluation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, global-variables

I want to set up global environment variables defining the current environment in which my Webpacked ReactJS app works (development, production, test or deployment). However I get this very weird error whenever trying to access my environment variable `__ENV__`.

The following similar pieces of code all fail with the same error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: deployment is not defined`, where deployment is the value of `__ENV__`, not it's ref name. The same happens no matter what value I give it. Here are the three samples:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
global.__ENV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(__ENV__); // crashes here otherwise crashes at next line
global.__PROD__ = __ENV__ == 'production';
global.__DEPLOY__ = __ENV__ == 'deployment';
global.__DEV__ = __ENV__ == 'development';
global.__TEST__ = __ENV__ == 'test';

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
window.__ENV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(__ENV__); // crashes here otherwise crashes at next line
window.__PROD__ = __ENV__ == 'production';
window.__DEPLOY__ = __ENV__ == 'deployment';
window.__DEV__ = __ENV__ == 'development';
window.__TEST__ = __ENV__ == 'test';

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
window.__ENV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(`${__ENV__}`); // crashes here otherwise crashes at next line
window.__PROD__ = `${__ENV__}` == 'production';
window.__DEPLOY__ = `${__ENV__}` == 'deployment';
window.__DEV__ = `${__ENV__}` == 'development';
window.__TEST__ = `${__ENV__}` == 'test';
```

Even weirder, this approach works instead:

```
const __ENV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(__ENV__);
global.__PROD__ = __ENV__ === 'production';
global.__DEPLOY__ = __ENV__ === 'deployment';
global.__DEV__ = __ENV__ === 'development';
global.__TEST__ = __ENV__ === 'test';
```

My Webpack configuration includes the following:

```
config.globals = {
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(config.env)
  },
  '__ENV__': config.env,
  '__DEPLOY__': config.env === '"deployment"',
  '__DEV__': config.env === '"development"',
  '__PROD__': config.env === '"production"',
  '__TEST__': config.env === '"test"'
};

webpack_config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.globals)
);
```

Any idea why this is a thing?

If this can be of any help, my codebase is transpiled from ES2015 with stage-0 proposals enabled and then shipped as a single bundle using Webpack.

Comment: Your first 7 lines of code works just fine in nodejs v6.9.2.  What are you running it in when you get the error you describe?

Comment: This is running in the latest version of Chrome atm (58.0.3029.81 (64-bit))

Answer (score 4):

The only reason why this would happen is if you configured your build tool replace global references to `__ENV__` with something else.

So the build tool will replace

```
console.log(__ENV__);
```

with

```
console.log(development);
```

This fails in strict mode because the variable `development` is not defined.

You are not showing how you configured your build tool, but instead of doing something like

```
replace('__ENV__', 'development')
```

it should be

```
replace('__ENV__' , '"development"')
```

so that the build tool inserts a *string literal* into the code (instead of a variable name).

(if the value comes from a variable, pass it through `JSON.stringify` first, that will add the quotes)

Comment: (Updated OP with Webpack config) Indeed this seems to have been the source of the error - Adding JSON.stringify( ... ) around each of the variables seems to shut down the error. However adding a print of the `__ENV__` variable before the first line of the third sample prints undefined. Any idea?